# Splitting one string into two or more rows in R while copying other columns

Tags: r, string, split

I have a string in a row of my dataframe df that has numbers and letters after the last underscore. Those letters can be an S T or Y with numbers occurring after them denoting where a phosphorylation happens in the protein, and there can be 1 to 9 sets of these. I want that string split IF there is more than one letter and the other columns copied. For example,

```
# Define the input strings
string1 <- "A01235_414_429_2_2_Y414T418S687"
string2 <- "C2"
string3 <- "C3"

# Create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(Column1 = string1, Column2 = string2, Column3 = string3)

# Print the dataframe
print(df)


# And the new code should yield; 

print(new_df) 


                 Column1 Column2 Column3
1 A01235_414_429_2_2_Y414       C2       C3
2 A01235_414_429_2_2_T418       C2       C3
3 A01235_414_429_2_2_S687       C2       C3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr`/`tidyr` method:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest
df %>%
  mutate(
    last = sub(".*_", "", Column1),
    mult = regmatches(last, gregexpr("[TYS][0-9]+", last))
  ) %>%
  unnest(mult) %>%
  mutate(Column1 = paste0(sub("_[^_]*$", "_", Column1), mult)) %>%
  select(-last, -mult)
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   Column1                 Column2 Column3
#   <chr>                   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 A01235_414_429_2_2_Y414 C2      C3     
# 2 A01235_414_429_2_2_T418 C2      C3     
# 3 A01235_414_429_2_2_S687 C2      C3
```

It might be possible (with more regex and a bit more work) to use `tidyr::separate_rows`, but since there's no clear delimiter I think it'll be about the same amount of code as above (if not more).

The `regmatches(last, gregexpr(..))` bit is operating on the substrings after the last `_`, and *only* that portion; and its purpose is to extract any substring that starts with `[TYS]` and is followed by one or more numbers.

It might be informative to see the results after the first `mutate(.)`, notice the list-column for what it is (not a comma-delimited string column), and understand then how the following `unnest` and `mutate` clean up the data.

---

*Edit*: this also works with repeated letters in one string, as in

```r
df <- structure(list(Column1 = c("A01235_414_429_2_2_Y414T418S687", "A2A123_1532_1541_2_2_S1532S1535"), Column2 = c("C2", "C2"), Column3 = c("C3", "C3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
df
#                           Column1 Column2 Column3
# 1 A01235_414_429_2_2_Y414T418S687      C2      C3
# 2 A2A123_1532_1541_2_2_S1532S1535      C2      C3
df %>%
  mutate(
    last = sub(".*_", "", Column1),
    mult = regmatches(last, gregexpr("[TYS][0-9]+", last))
  ) %>%
  unnest(mult) %>%
  mutate(Column1 = paste0(sub("_[^_]*$", "_", Column1), mult)) %>%
  select(-last, -mult)
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   Column1                    Column2 Column3
#   <chr>                      <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 A01235_414_429_2_2_Y414    C2      C3     
# 2 A01235_414_429_2_2_T418    C2      C3     
# 3 A01235_414_429_2_2_S687    C2      C3     
# 4 A2A123_1532_1541_2_2_S1532 C2      C3     
# 5 A2A123_1532_1541_2_2_S1535 C2      C3
```

Comment: Thank you very much, R2! I want to let you know that I really appreciate your time and work on these. I don't know why it wasn't working before, something I did when I converted to my DF and column, working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
pat <- "[YTS]\\d+"
df %>%
    mutate(Column1 = list(str_c(
        gsub(pat, "", Column1),
        str_extract_all(Column1, pat, TRUE)
    ))) %>%
    unnest(Column1)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Column1                 Column2 Column3
  <chr>                   <chr>   <chr>
1 A01235_414_429_2_2_Y414 C2      C3
2 A01235_414_429_2_2_T418 C2      C3
3 A01235_414_429_2_2_S687 C2      C3
```